# Desktop environment won't show up when a wrong password has been entered before entering the right one

Tags: gnome, login, password

My system is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, with GNOME 3.28.1.
In the login screen, if I enter the wrong password, it shows me the the message "Sorry, it didn't work", and then I continue to enter the right one. Then the login screen fades away but continue to show me the purplish background but not the desktop environment. However, if I enter the right password on the first try, everything goes normal. Also if I press cancel button after the "Sorry, it didn't work" message was shown and reenter the login screen, everything works fine.
Does anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: Known bug:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1766137